# Updating ObservableCollection in ViewModel from dropped files in ListBox in the view - WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

I am trying to find out how to process drag and dropped Dropped files in my listbox in a usercontrol and bind them to update an ObservableCollection in my ViewModel.

Here's my listBox in XAML:

```
    <ListBox x:Name="listDrop" Height="50" Margin="0,0,0,0"  AllowDrop="True" Drop="dropfiles"  >

    </ListBox>
```

Now the codebehind:

```
public partial class ProcessXML : UserControl
{


    public ProcessXML()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


    }

    private void dropfiles(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
    {


        string[] droppedFiles = null;

        if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
        {
            droppedFiles = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
        }

        if ((null == droppedFiles) || (!droppedFiles.Any())) { return; }

        listDrop.Items.Clear();

        foreach (string s in droppedFiles)
        {
            listDrop.Items.Add(s);
        }


    }
}
```

This lists the path to the files being dropped, working fine,  but how do I send that info or use this to process it?

I would like to send this data to my Viewmodel, ideally to an ObservableCollection and then process each items but I've been scratching my head and can't find a way. How would I accomplish that?

Comment: `EventToCommand` ?

Comment: it didn't work as the eventargs e wasn't recognised in the viewmodel, could you somehow elaborate in case I missed something? Merci

Comment: Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing in your code to indicate that you even have a viewmodel, or what you're using it for. I'm going to assume -- wrongly, I suspect -- that it's the `DataContext` for the usercontrol.

If you want your viewmodel to do something when files are dropped, you can have it handle the `CollectionChanged` event of its `DropFiles` collection, or you can give it a method for the file-drop handler to call.

```
private void dropfiles(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] droppedFiles = null;

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        droppedFiles = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
    }


    if ((null == droppedFiles) || (!droppedFiles.Any())) { return; }

    var myVM = DataContext as MyViewModel;

    //   MyViewModel.DropFiles should be ObservableCollection<String>
    myVM.DropFiles.Clear();

    foreach (string s in droppedFiles)
    {
        myVM.DropFiles.Add(s);
    }
}
```

Alternate:

```
private void dropfiles(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string[] droppedFiles = null;

    if (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.FileDrop))
    {
        droppedFiles = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop, true) as string[];
    }


    if ((null == droppedFiles) || (!droppedFiles.Any())) { return; }

    var myVM = DataContext as MyViewModel;

    myVM.DoFileDrop(droppedFiles);
}
```

MyViewModel.cs

```
public void DoFileDrop(IEnumerable<String> filePaths)
{
    DropFiles.Clear();
    foreach (var s in filePaths)
        DropFiles.Add(s);

    //  Do other stuff if you want to
}
```

XAML

```
<ListBox 
    x:Name="listDrop" 
    Height="50" 
    Margin="0,0,0,0"  
    AllowDrop="True" 
    Drop="dropfiles"  
    ItemsSource="{Binding DropFiles}"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you! that did the trick. The obvious part I was missing was how to access my instance of the Datacontext, but var myVM = DataContext as MyViewModel; was what was needed!

Comment: I believe I did but not sure you could see it as I'm a noob here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are binding **ViewModel** to **DataContext** of **ProcessXML** then you can access your **ViewModel** like this:

```
private void dropfiles(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    // some code goes here ...


    var vm = this.DataContext as ViewModelType;
    if (vm == null) return;

    // Do your stuff with vm instance below
}
```

**EDITED**

I think you want something like this:

```
<Window x:Name="root">
    <Grid x:Name="someParentControl">
        <controls:ProcessXML ParentViewModel={Binding Path=DataContext, ElementName=root}/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And **ProcessXML** code behind

```
public partial class ProcessXML : UserControl
{
    public ProcessXML()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    DependencyProperty ParentViewModelProperty = DependencyProperty
        .Register("ParentViewModel", typeof(ViewModelType), typeof(ProcessXML), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public ViewModelType ParentViewModel
    {
        get { return (ViewModelType)GetValue(ParentViewModelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ParentViewModelProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's also possible, that your user control ProcessXML inherits DataContext of it's parent if you're not setting it explicitly

Comment: thanks but where should I put this? I've tried inserting it in the ProcessXML UserControl and it didn't work. Should I put this in the constructor of the usercontrol?

Comment: @jayNorth What does "doesn't work" mean? Please explain what went wrong.

Comment: That works TEИ. developer, I didn't write the  var vm = this.DataContext as ViewModelType; correctly but now it's ok. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is how to achieve that using [MvvmLightLibs](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLightLibs/5.3.0):**

- `ObservableCollection<T>`
- `EventToCommand`

**Window XAML:**

```
<Window
    x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:wpfApp1="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance wpfApp1:Model}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <wpfApp1:Model />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <Grid>
        <wpfApp1:UserControl1 />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Window code:**

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**User control XAML:**

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="WpfApp1.UserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance local:Model}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid>
        <ListBox AllowDrop="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Files}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="Drop">
                    <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Load}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**User control code:**

```
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class UserControl1
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.CommandWpf;

namespace WpfApp1
{
    public class Model : ViewModelBase
    {
        public Model()
        {
            Files = new ObservableCollection<string>();

            Load = new RelayCommand<DragEventArgs>(e =>
            {
                var files = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.FileDrop) as string[];
                if (files == null)
                    return;

                foreach (var file in files)
                {
                    Files.Add(file);
                }
            });
        }

        public RelayCommand<DragEventArgs> Load { get; }

        public ObservableCollection<string> Files { get; }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example, obviously you will want to further adjust it to your needs.

Comment: I wasn't aware I could pass eventsargs this way, this works great thank you!

Comment: If my answer satisfies you then consider accepting or up-voting it :)

Comment: I did upvote but it doesn't show up as I'm still new here (not enough rep points I guess?)